# Spark Closure cleaning and serialization OOM

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have been stuck on this problem for the last few days:

I am attempting to run random forest from MLLIB, it gets through most of it, but breaks when doing a mapPartition operation. The following stack trace is shown:

```
: An error occurred while calling o94.trainRandomForestModel. 
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123) 
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117) 
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93) 
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189) 
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44) 
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294) 
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122) 
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2021) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:703) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:702) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:702) 
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$.findBestSplits(DecisionTree.scala:625) 
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:235) 
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest$.trainClassifier(RandomForest.scala:291) 
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainRandomForestModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:742) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231) 
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379) 
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259) 
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133) 
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) 
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems to me that it's trying to serialize the mapPartitions closure, but runs out of space doing so. However I don't understand how it could run out of space when I gave the driver ~190GB for a file that's 45MB.

I have a cluster setup on AWS such that my master is a r3.8xlarge along with two r3.4xlarge workers. I have the following configurations:

```
spark version: 1.5.0 
----------------------------------- 
spark.executor.memory 32000m 
spark.driver.memory 230000m 
spark.driver.cores 10 
spark.executor.cores 5 
spark.executor.instances 17 
spark.driver.maxResultSize 0 
spark.storage.safetyFraction 1 
spark.storage.memoryFraction 0.9 
spark.storage.shuffleFraction 0.05 
spark.default.parallelism 128
```

The master machine has approximately 240 GB of ram and each worker has about 120GB of ram.

I load in a relatively tiny RDD of MLLIB LabeledPoint objects, with each holding sparse vectors inside. This RDD has a total size of roughly 45MB. My sparse vector has a total length of ~15 million while only about 3000 or so are non-zeros.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? I have the same issue.